# Visual Studio Code - How to change the badge color for error tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]See the black dot..??

I see a badge on the editor's tabs showing that somthing has been modified. I use to see other badges that showed errors, however, I don't see them anymore. What setting do I use to enable the badges to show errors?

How we see the black badge for a tab where changes have been made, similarly, it would show a red badge (large dot) for the tabs(files) with errors. Now I can't see those. Also, I would like to set custom colour for it.

Comment: There is no badge called Error-badge, however, there are other types of badges that display errors, but its hard to know which one your asking about. Can you share a screen shot with us?

Comment: find the theme name for the color and customize this theme name

Answer (score 1):

*You can customize your active Visual Studio Code color theme with the workbench.colorCustomizations user setting.*

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#00AA00"
  }
}
```

**Color Formats**

*Color values can be defined in the RGB color model with an alpha channel for transparency. As format, the following hexadecimal notations are supported: #RGB, #RGBA, #RRGGBB and #RRGGBBAA. R (red), G (green), B (blue), and A (alpha) are hexadecimal characters (0-9, a-f or A-F). The three-digit notation (#RGB) is a shorter version of the six-digit form (#RRGGBB) and the four-digit RGB notation (#RGBA) is a shorter version of the eight-digit form (#RRGGBBAA). For example #e35f is the same color as #ee3355ff.

If no alpha value is defined, it defaults to ff (opaque, no transparency). If alpha is set to 00, the color is fully transparent.

Some colors should not be opaque in order to not cover other annotations. Check the color descriptions to see to which colors this applies.

*

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: This isn't even anywhere close to what he was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

To see `Problems` decorations in the file tabs, enable this setting:

```
Problems > Decorations: Enabled
"Show Errors & Warnings on files and folder."
```

I don't see any way to change the colors of the tab Problem indicators.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what your looking for, let me know if they work, and which one in particular fixed your issue so we can edit your question and write it to properly address the issue your having.

```
{
   // Make sure the tab extends where the button & modified icon is @
   "workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "right",

   // Turn on badges & colors for the Source Control decorations
   "workbench.editor.decorations.badges": true,
   "workbench.editor.decorations.colors": true

   // Bonus: If you want them turned on in your File explorer too, use this:
   "explorer.decorations.badges": true
   "explorer.decorations.colors": true
}
```

Comment: This I know, doesn't help. Still can't see the badges on tabs with errors.

Comment: This din't work the way I wanted, but at least it gives me an error count in place of a badge (haven't been able to change the colour still).

Answer (score 0):

To change the **colors of tabs** including `Problems` and `Terminal`, add this code in `settings.json`:

```
"panel.background": "#your color code"
```

To change the **color of badge** of `Problems`,  add this code in `settings.json`:

```
"badge.background": "#your color code"
```