# How to disable VSCode's tab highlighting for files with problems?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, visual-studio-code, ide, syntax-highlighting

When a file in VSCode has problems in it (e.g. unreachable code), the title of it's tab turns orange/yellow, which overwrites git's highlighting (that signalizes modified or new file).

I want to disable this. I tried about every setting I could find, but none changes the tab's appearance when there are problems in it. There is a setting for errors, but not for problems.

[A screenshot of a file that has a problem in it, and it's tab's title is orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G0Nr.png)

[An example screenshot of normal git highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWM8e.png)

Comment: how is it interfering with the diff decoration? the diff decoration is done using letters in the tab handle (A,M,D).

Comment: It is done both by letters (called "badges" in VSCode) and by color (at least in my theme). But I have badges disabled and want it to be differentiated by color nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially solved by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark) in [VSCode - How to change the badge color for error tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75621360/13284148). **It seems like there is currently no way to only disable or change the color of warnings specifically**, but there is an option to disable colors for all problems (both errors and warning), which leaves only git coloring visible. Not an ideal solution, but it's better than nothing.

Solution from Mark's answer:

> To see Problems decorations in the file tabs, enable this setting:

```
Problems > Decorations: Enabled
"Show Errors & Warnings on files and folder."
```